# Can't import java.util.Calendar in IntelliJ

Tags: java, android-studio, intellij-idea

[image]
[image]

When I'm following the codes in a book, it shows me can't import `java.util.Calendar`, does anybody know about it?
This is only happening in IntelliJ, Android Studio works fine...

Comment: Very strange beahaviour. It seems that you manually deleted the class from the jdk installation. Try to download another jdk, change the references to the jdk in IntelliJ. It is possible that IntelliJ and Android Studio use differents JDK.

Comment: I checked the path of JDK in Android Studio and IntelliJ, they are the same... Thanks for replying

Answer (score 1):

Please try File | Invalidate Caches and restart.